# Countdown timer with ajax loaded content (jquery mobile) not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, xhtml

I am having some trouble getting a countdown timer to work on my jQuery mobile page. If I have it load on a static html page it works as it should (see that page here:http://www.beingproperties.com/match-game). when you hit the start game the timer starts.

I have recently ported this over to the jQuery mobile framework and the timer is not working on that site (see this here by going to the link and clicking the 'multi-page link, then the start game link): http://www.beingproperties.com/match-game/home.html).

I have tied using 'pageshow' as scene below and though I get it to work and throw an alert, once I add in my code to execute nothing happens.

```
$('#shapesPage').live('pageshow', function () {
```

I know that it's something regarding the ajax loaded page, though all other jQuery fires on this page except for the countdown timer. I'm at a loss and would much appreciate a kick in the right direction.

I used the inspector and it's not very informative. Any insight to get this resolved, or proper ways to debug these types of issues would be much appreciated. thanks in advance. -Chris

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source for `home.html`, it seems that you haven't included `js/plugins.js`, only `js/index.js`.

I know you've included it in `shapes.html`, but JQM is a bit weird about loading external scripts when loading a page via ajax, as stated in the [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html):

> The simplest approach when building a jQuery Mobile site is to reference the same set of stylesheets and scripts in the head of every page. If you need to load in specific scripts or styles for a particular page, we recommend binding logic to the pageinit event (details below) to run necessary code when a specific page is created (which can be determined by its id attribute, or a number of other ways). Following this approach will ensure that the code executes if the page is loaded directly or is pulled in and shown via Ajax.

**Edit**: You can not call any functions that modify the DOM until it is fully loaded. This is signaled in JQM by the `pageinit` event. Read about [scripting](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-scripting.html) and [events](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) for more info.

Try surrounding your javascript for `shapes.html` with

```
$( document ).delegate("#shapesPage", "pageinit", function() {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, though I have tried that as well. the plugins.js file is being referenced without it being in the home page. If you click the lower right panel it will make a match and add to the total. The total jQuery is in that plugins.js file.

Comment: Ah, looking again, it's because `plugin.js` is loaded immediately when loading `shapes.html` - *before* the DOM has fully initialized. Also stated in the documentation, you should call the code after the `pageinit` event, which will be fired once the DOM is ready.